# How to pass jQuery function as another function's argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, monads

I want to create function which takes one function as a parameter (another function) and returns function taking arguments which will be apply to the first one.

It's monadic idea like this:

```
function creator(fun) {
    return function (arg) {
        fun(arg);
    };
}

$(function () {
    var printer = creator(alert);
    printer("foo bar");
})
```

The problem is that I can't google or figure out how to do the same with jQuery functions:

```
function show_and_change(fun) {
    return function (el, attr, value) {
        console.log(el.fun(attr)
        el.fun(attr, value);
    }
}

$(function () {
    var my_mod = show_and_change($.fn.attr);
    my_mod($("#one"), "foo", "bar2");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`el.fun` will literally try to access the property `fun` on `el` (which doesn't exist). Instead you want to call `fun` (like you did in the first example) but also set its [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value to the jQuery object:

```
fun.call(el, attr, value);
```

Learn more about [**`.call`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fcall) and [**`.apply`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).